# QGIS2web OL3 does not show map title

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis2web

Despite having

```
<title>Threatened Ecosystems of South Africa</title>
```

in the html file, the Open Layers map does not include a title like Leaflet does. Is there some way around this, or is this just how it is unfortunately?

Comment: Please be more specific: Where do you want a title to appear? What are your settings regarding this? Which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just how it is at the moment, I'm afraid. Leaflet has a built-in method for adding the title to the map, but OpenLayers does not. It can be developed, and there is an existing issue on Github which includes this:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/498#issuecomment-306830753

In that comment, Ola's code is the way to tackle this: place a `<div>` within the `<map>`, and then use CSS to style it.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the `index.html` file that qgis2web produces you'll see the title tags in the head section of the file.

`<title>This is an OL3 map</title>`

The text between the tags is displayed on the tab on your browser.

[image: Firefox tabs]

[image: Chrome tabs]

[image: IE11 tabs]

If you want a title on the map itself then you need to add some text in the body section of `index.html`

`<body>
        <h1 align=center>This is an OL3 map</h1>
        <div id="map">`

[image: title in body section]

Comment: Ha! Beat me to it, Tom.